# Integrating HTK results

Tags: speech-recognition, htk

Good day to all,

I'm new in speech recognition.

Right now, I'm working with HTK to deal with speech recognition.
I'm having result of 55% accuracy.
I would like to ask:

1. Can I integrate HTK results to make live recognizer from it?
2. What should I deal then in order to make live recognizer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTK live recognizer is called ATK. You can download it from HTK website.

Answer (score 0):

For small vocabulary tasks you can use HTK's `HVite` tool, for large vocabulary speech recognition you can use `HDecode`. It's downloaded and installed separately, and has different license terms. You can read more about `HDecode` in HTK Book. You will need Language Model for continuous speech recognition or grammar file for recognizing limited set of spoken commands.